# count checkboxes in a form using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have quite a lot of check boxes on one form. The check boxes are in different sections of the form. I would like to count the number of checkboxes at the end of each section on my form.

For example I have 6 sections within my form and I have between 6 and 10 checkboxes within each section. I would like to have a textbox with a number value at the end of each section telling me how many check boxes were check within that particular section.

Does anyone have a script for that? I have a snippet from support staff but they don't have a full solution and I don't know JavaScript well enough to finish it. I'm through trying to figure it out so i can finish it. Here is the snippet they sent me:

```js
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function countcheck(checkName){

    inputElems = document.getElementsByName(checkName);
    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < inputElems.length; i++) {
        if (inputElems.checked === true) {
            count++;
            document.getElementById("teval_engage7").value = count;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The script will only count checked checkboxes within that group only. Basically you will need a function for each of your checkbox so that you can have separated counters. This will also require an attribute to your checkbox according to the function in question:

```
onclick="countcheck(this.name);"
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
var cb_counts = {};
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var input = inputs[i];
    if (input.type = 'checkbox' && input.checked) {
        if (cb_counts[input.name]) {
            cb_counts[input.name]++;
        } else {
            (cb_counts[input.name] = 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the object `cb_counts` contains properties with the name of each group of checkboxes, and the values are the counts. Do with this what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick reply. I use a application call rsform which helps to make forms. On the script I have "teval_engage7" is the text box which stores the value of the number of checkboxes that have been checked. "onclick="countcheck(this.name);"" is the trigger I place under each checkbox question. So when I go to the form and click on a checkbox with that trigger attached to it, the value of "1" shows up in the teval_engage7 text box. The next check box I click on then shows "2" in the teval_engage7 text box. My question is, can you te me using this script you wrote where the values are stored so I can substitute that name for my textbox name. Also, do I use my same trigger  "onclick="countcheck(this.name);"" to attach to my checkbox attibute area to trigger the count?

Thanks